# IIS 7 - Windows Server 2008 combine to make file locked, causing IIS to overload

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, filesystems

I have this issue where approximately once a year, one of my images in my asp.net web app becomes locked. By locked I mean you can't read/write/delete it, and if you try to, your remote machine crashes.

It then causes my worker processes to not release the related page, filling the worker process memory quickly. They try to recycle sometimes, but then multiple ones are left open and the ram quickly runs out as multiple w3wps are hitting 4-5 gb. I'm guessing the old stale w3wps are not able to be deleted because they are referencing the locked image.

This has happened twice now, and the file is undeletable, I mean absolutely undeletable. Tried force deleting, tried removing all holds/locks on the file using some utilities, tried deleting from a mac. If you try to delete from windows explorer on a remote machine, your entire explorer freezes and there is nothing you can do except hard-reset the machine.

The only way to get this file unlocked is to reboot the server with the file on it.

Any ideas on what a good step would be to figuring out how this is happening?

Comment: I also work with chuckp16, perhaps a better word than locked is corrupted. To make it clear there are several webservers hosting IIS their webfiles are pointed at the same share on a file server. The files in question are normal .png images less than 3kb. It is like the file server keeps a cached version of the file in memory that becomes corrupted resulting in the symptoms chuckp16 pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on, but this does seem like a classic symptom of an rdbss.sys locking bug.  I would start by ensuring that rdbss.sys and the client redirector (mrxsmbxx.sys) components are at the recommended versions.

List of currently available hotfixes for the File Services technologies in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2008 R2

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2473205